# Combobox ValueMember not working with MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

My `ComboBox` controls display *publishername* and *authorlastname* and stores the *publisherid* and *authorid*.

When I run my code, it does display *publishername* and *authorlastname* with the `ValueMember` of  *publisherid* and *authorid* however when the insert query runs it literally tries to insert the words `_publisherid_` and `_authorid_`.

ComboBox Code:

```vb
Private Sub addbook_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;database=librarydatabase;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
    Dim table As New DataTable

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from publishertable", mysqlconn)

    da.Fill(table)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "publishername"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PublisherId"

    Dim pa As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from authortable", mysqlconn)

    pa.Fill(table)
    ComboBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource(table, Nothing)
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "authorlastname"
    ComboBox2.ValueMember = "authorid"

End Sub
```

Insert Code:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;database=librarydatabase"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        query = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;insert into booktable(ISBNno,bookname,dateofpublication,genre,duodecimal,copies,copiesinstock,authorid,publisherid) Values('" & ISBNno.Text & "','" & Title.Text & "','" & dateofpublication.Text & "','" & genre.Text & "','" & duodecimal.Text & "','" & copies.Text & "','" & copies.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.ValueMember & "', '" & ComboBox1.ValueMember & "');SET foreign_key_checks = 1"

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show(query)

        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()


    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: you should be using `SelectedValue` instead of `ValueMember`

Comment: If you want to save publishername in the database pass the ComboBox1.SelectedText.

Comment: Your code could be vulnerable to SQL Injection, conversion errors, and truncation of data, [you should **ALWAYS** use parameterised queries.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: @PRABA That's not correct. That is for highlighted text, they would need the normal `Text` property

Comment: You can also go directly to table `ComboBox2.DataSource = table`. And also, always set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMemeber` before `DataSource`. - google **why**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using SelectedValue instead of ValueMember

```
query = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;insert into booktable(ISBNno,bookname,dateofpublication,genre,duodecimal,copies,copiesinstock,authorid,publisherid) Values('" & ISBNno.Text & "','" & Title.Text & "','" & dateofpublication.Text & "','" & genre.Text & "','" & duodecimal.Text & "','" & copies.Text & "','" & copies.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.ValueMember & "', '" & ComboBox1.ValueMember & "');SET foreign_key_checks = 1"
```

should be

```
query = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;insert into booktable(ISBNno,bookname,dateofpublication,genre,duodecimal,copies,copiesinstock,authorid,publisherid) Values('" & ISBNno.Text & "','" & Title.Text & "','" & dateofpublication.Text & "','" & genre.Text & "','" & duodecimal.Text & "','" & copies.Text & "','" & copies.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.SelectedValue & "', '" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "');SET foreign_key_checks = 1"
```

Comment: @TheShayaan If it worked why don't you accept the answer?